# Why do some apps use Java class names like C10265b?

Tags: android, class, naming

I have seen the source code of some Android apps, and noticed that most apps use Java class names like `C10265b`, `C10264a`. Why do they name classes like that?

Comment: This sounds like maybe they are autogenerated classes.  Perhaps you are looking at native library stuff, or maybe this is an app which was generated using something like Xamarin or React Native.

Comment: did u decompile and check ? , if so then reason may be proguard

Comment: Its just Obfuscation to prevent from reverse engineering. Can be `Proguard` or `Dexguard` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They used [proguard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) to safe their codes from reverse engineering. **This is a technique to avoid being hacked**. At the very first their code was simple like us. But after encryption it is **C10264a**